# Properties of a an entire function: Solution verification

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

I would like to answer the following question

[image]

**My solution:**

(i) Since $f$ is entire it follows that $f$ is holomorphic and hence $f$ is analytic. Since $f$ is analytic on the whole $\mathbb{C}$ it follows that $f$ is analytic on the origin. Therefore we can write $f(z)= \sum a_n z^n $. If $f(z)/z \rightarrow 0$ as $|z| \rightarrow \infty$ then

$$\lim_{|z|\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\sum a_n z^n}{z}=\lim_{|z|\rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_0}{z} + a_1 + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_n z^{n-1}=\lim_{|z|\rightarrow \infty}a_1 + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_n z^{n-1}=0 $$

This must be true for all $z$ outside of the disc $D(0,N)$ (where $N$ is sufficiently large).  Since the function we are taking a limit of is analytic then by analytic continuation it follows that $a_1 + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_nz^{n-1}=0$ for all $z$.  From this we get that
$$f(z)=a_0$$
and hence $f$ is constant.

(ii) Since $f$ is analytic it follows that if $f'(z)\neq 0$ then $f$ has an analytic isomorphism (by the inverse mapping theorem). The existence of the analytic isomorphism implies that $f$ is surjective and hence $f$ maps the whole of $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$.  Now suppose that the condition in (ii) true. Since $f$ is subjective we can pick $z_0$ s.t. $f(z_0)=b$ and hence $|f(z_0)-f(z_0|=0$ which is a contradiction (could have also used the continuity of analytic functions here so that we have $|f(w=z_0+\delta)-f(z_0)|<\epsilon)$. Therefore the assumption that $f'(z)\neq 0$ must be false. Hence $f$ is constant.

**My question:** Is this correct?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon this is what I was constructing. Show that the given condition is contradictory $f$ being a surjection. Is it not?

Comment: No, sorry. What is the statement of the inverse mapping theorem that you have? I am anyway concerned that it is too strong for the problem, but I think there is something wrong going on with the application of that theorem. For example, apply Liouville to the bounded function $\frac 1{f(z)-b}$, which is entire. In fact, there is something off : the exponential map is entire and is not surjective, but has non-zero derivative everywhere.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon thank you for the comment. You are right, Liousville's Theorem does indeed work. In regards to the Inverse Mapping theorem, I have it as "Let $f$ be an analytic function on an open set $U$ containing $z_0$. Suppose that $f'(z_0) \neq 0$. Then $f$ is a local analytic isomorphism at $z_0$.  Could you clarify what you mean "by   too strong for the problem"?

Comment: What I meant was, that the inverse mapping theorem is difficult to prove (more than Liouville's theorem for sure) and is probably a very strong tool for what is a much simpler problem. Also, a local analytic isomorphism is *locally surjective*, but not *globally surjective*. So for example, even if  $f'(z_0) \neq 0$ held everywhere, we could *still* not say the function is surjective, because when you put these local surjective images together you don't get all the complex numbers. Look up the complex exponential function for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part $1$ is fine, it is proved correctly.

For part $2$, we use Liouville's theorem on the function $\frac 1{f(z)-b}$, which is an entire function because the denominator is non-zero (and division, shifting etc. preserve entirety if valid), and also is a *bounded* function since $$\left|\frac 1{f(z)-b}\right|= \frac 1{|f(z)-b|} < \frac 1{\epsilon}$$

for all $z$. Hence $\frac 1{f(z)-b}$ is constant, therefore $f$ is constant.

---

The inverse mapping theorem tells you this : if $f'(z) \neq 0$ at a point , then there exist neighbourhoods $U,V \subset \mathbb C$ with $z \in U$ and $f(z) \in V$ such that $f: U \to V$ is analytic and a bijection.

The problem with what you want to say is two-fold. First of all, what if $f'(z)=0$ at some point? Note that if $f'$ is *entirely* $0$, only then is $f$ constant, but if $f$ is not constant it is *still* possible for $f'$ to have zeros. So at these points you can't create such a map.

Next, *even if* the function has non-zero derivative at all points, it *still doesn't mean it is surjective*. This is because, even if for each point you take a neighbourhood around it for which the isomorphism exists, the $V$s put together don't give you the entire of $\mathbb C$. Take the exponential function as an example of this phenomena.

Here is a nice result on what the image of an entire map must be.

> Little Picard Theorem : Every nonconstant analytic function omits *at most one* complex number from its range. So at most one number cannot be the image of a non-constant entire map. The exponential map omits $0$, for example, but nothing else.